# Is it possible to return multiple values with multiple ifs? C#

Tags: c#, if-statement

```
    double GPoint = 0, GPer;
    string Des = null;
    
    Console.WriteLine("Enter your Equivalence Grade");
    GPer = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    
    if (GPer >= 95 && GPer <= 100)
        GPoint = 1.00;
        Des = "Excellent";
    
    if (GPer >= 91 && GPer <= 94)
        GPoint = 1.25;
        Des = "Superior";
    
    if (GPer >= 88 && GPer <= 90)
        GPoint = 1.50;
        Des = "Very Good";
    
    if (GPer >= 86 && GPer <= 87)
        GPoint = 1.75;
        Des = "Good";
    
    if (GPer >= 84 && GPer <= 85)
        GPoint = 2.00;
        Des = "Very Satisfactory";
    
    Console.WriteLine( "Your final grade is {0}, a {1} Grade."
                      ,GPoint
                      ,Des);
```

It only does the first variable correctly but the second value always prints the last if statement.
So it always returns "Very Satisfactory" on any value.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean, as there is no return statement in the code, so it is not "returning" anything.

Comment: What i meant is it only does the first variable, GPoint, correctly. so if i input 95 it prints 1.00 which is correct but it always prints the 2nd variable, the Des on the last IF statement

Comment: Yes, because you haven't put any braces around your `if` statement bodies - you seem to be assuming that the indentation does that for you, like in Python. It doesn't.

Comment: Also note that your code isn't "returning" anything... it's just assigning values to variables.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, in modern C# I'd probably do this with a switch expression and tuples (and I'd also change the local variable names to be more meaningful and idiomatically-cased)... but leaving that aside, the immediate problem is that your indentation suggests you think that this:

```cs
if (GPer >= 88 && GPer <= 90)
   GPoint = 1.50;
   Des = "Very Good";
```

... only assigns `Des` if the condition is met. That's not true. That code is equivalent to:

```cs
if (GPer >= 88 && GPer <= 90)
{
   GPoint = 1.50;
}
Des = "Very Good";
```

If your `if` statement body needs to contain multiple statements, you need to use a block body. Personally I would recommend *always* using a block body even if the body is only a single statement, but that's a matter of coding style. You can fix your code just by using block bodies for all your `if` statements, e.g.

```cs
if (GPer >= 88 && GPer <= 90)
{
   GPoint = 1.50;
   Des = "Very Good";
}
```